# How to set selection, selection args to filter results

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

This is the code I am using for `selection` and `selectionArgs` clauses.

```
 String where = db_contract.trans.TYPE + "=? AND " + db_contract.trans.BANK_NAME + "=? AND " + db_contract.trans.TIME+ ">=? AND " + db_contract.trans.TIME + "<=?";

  String[] whereArgs = new String[]{type_name, bank_name, from_date, to_date};
```

User selects to query results based on his filter need so `type_name` , `bank_name`, `from_date`, `to_date` are may/maynot be filled. So, I wrote this code to replace those 4 variables.

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("bank_name")) {
            bank_name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("bank_name");
        }else{
            bank_name = "?";
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("type_name")) {
            type_name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("type_name");
        }else{
            type_name = "?";
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("from_date")) {
            from_date =  getIntent().getStringExtra("from_date");
        }else{
            from_date = "?";
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("to_date")) {
            to_date =  getIntent().getStringExtra("to_date");
        }else{
            to_date = "?";
        }
```

It's giving an empty set of results. How to query results if the user gave no filter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various methods and got the solution.

This is the link to the code : https://github.com/vishnu8742/Balance-It/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vishnu/anon/balanceit/trans_list.java

Hope it may help someone.